# Getting 401 error when trying to access /api/login in Grails 3 and Spring Security Rest

Tags: mysql, spring, rest, grails

I am developing a REST API using **Grails 3** and Spring Security Rest plugin.
I am using **MySQL 5.7.19 as my backend.**
The app seems to work fine and I can access all endpoints when I use default backend provided by Grails.
But when I use **MySQL** as my back end I get a **401 error** when trying to access **/api/login endpoint**.
All kinds of help will be highly appreciated.
Following is my application.groovy file but I don't think there is an issue within this since the app works fine when using default backend provided by Grails.

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'todo.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'todo.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'todo.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', filters: 'none'],
    [pattern: '/api/**',         filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter']
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access end point  /api/login which indicates that you are trying to implement spring security for REST, how are you invoking this end point? I mean are you trying to access it through browser? Try accessing though something like Postman in a post request. Also in the body pass the required json something like this

{
   "username" : "someusername",
   "password" : "somepassword"
   }

Obviously someusername and somepassword needs to be replaced with valid user/password combination existing in your database.

Comment: I have tried using Postman and also tried curl in Linux. 
I have tried with the correct headers as well as the correct body with the right username and password. As I mentioned the problem is only when I use MySQL backend. The login api calls work fine when using Grails default HSQL database.